# iPhone Calendar Day View

Tags: iphone, ios, view, calendar

Before jumping on me, please read my question carefully :D. I know there are already a few answers here, but there is none related about the actual view. I know how to implement the logic, using a UIScrollView and etc. But my question is this: how do you suggest to implement the View. (I want to add three instances of this custom UIView to a UIScrollView). I was thinking of drawing the lines in drawRect and adding the UILabels in initWithFrame. Or should I build a different custom UIView containing my line, and after that add it multiple times to the custom UIView representing my Calendar View?

Right now I am only interested in creating the background view (time labels and lines), I will worry about the events later.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tapku Library for Calendar view in iPhone the following link for tapku library, Implements it https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

**Download library and USE TKCalendarMonthView** for calendar..

Answer (score 1):

Checkout i created day view using Tapku library [DayView](https://github.com/safecase123/Calender)

I have customized to some extent just like `iCalender`

Comment: your effort is great. But you missed one important thing. That is, "all-day" events. Please add this functionality as well to make it really usable.

Comment: @AsifBilal : Can you help here?